# Spring - How to protect my api with client\secret for server to server using

Tags: java, spring, security

In Spring boot - how can I protect my API with client\secret for server to server implementation?
The users details will saved in out custom DB

I look for an example without form-login

Thanks!

I listened to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaUGKnA7aro
But it use form-data (interactive with user)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring security plugin with jwt token. Check out this documentation, https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt it's very well explained. To add on that check out cores; the cores ensure only the allowed client url can communicate with your api, check out this https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use client\secret protection without jwt